# Go Back To Previous View Controller From Back Button and using .xib files swift 3

Tags: swift, xib

this is my first time using .xib file and have an view controller, i made back button programmatically.
i tried this but doesn't work

make back button :

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(SearchResultOnlineVC.back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

action :

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

i also try

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know if the function is called (for example with simple print statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```